# Saving an editable dataTable ends up in all properties being the same

Tags: jsf-2, datatable

A page in my JSF 2.0 application, populates a dataTable with the number
of teachers (in form of teacherIds) from a particular school(database operation). 
Against each row, I need to assign two properties, an integer value (intValue)
and a String value (strValue). When I submit the page for saving it to the database, 
I end up saving same strValue and intValue for all teachers from the teacherList.
Maybe I am not knowing how to use a datatable, I am kind of following "http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf". Could anyone suggest any other alternative or a fix. My code is pasted below. Thanks!

The Bean

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyBean implements Serializable{

    private Integer indId;
    private Integer teacherId;
    private Integer schoolId;
    private String strValue;
    private Integer intValue;
    private List<Teacher> teacherList;
    private List<Att> tList;

    public myBean(){
        tList = new ArrayList<Att>();

        // Some database operations to load the att.xhtml page
        indId = findId();
        teacherList = teacherDataProvider(schoolId);    
    }

    public void attEntry(){

        for (int i = 0;i<teacherList.size();i++){

            tList.add(new Att(this.teacherList.get(i).getTeacherId(),
                                                            this.indId,
                                                            this.strValue,
                                                            this.intValue,
                                                            );
            dataProvider.addAtt(tList.get(i)); // call for database archival from the DAO   
        }
    }

    // getters & setters

}
```

`att.xhtml`

```
<h:dataTable id="teachers" class="table table-condensed" 
    value="#{myBean.teacherList}" var="t">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Teacher Id" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{t.teacherId}" />
    </h:column> 

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Att" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{myBean.intValue}" />
    </h:column>

    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Comments" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputTextarea value="#{myBean.strValue}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>      
<div>
    <h:commandButton action="#{myBean.attEntry}" value="Submit" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not about datatables, the problem is about failure to get a grasp of JSF basics. JSF is doing exactly what you tell it to do. And what you tell is basically to have ***one*** `Integer` and **one** `String` property of your bean alongside *a **list** of `Teacher`* objects, which obviously yields inconsistencies.

What implicitly follows from your question is the exact opposite: you want an integer-string pair to be attached to *every* instance of your class. This presumes that you either want to store these two values within a `Teacher` class, or enclose a `Teacher` object together with the two values in a wrapper class:

1. Add two fields to `Teacher` class:

   ```
   public class Teacher {

       private int intValue;//getter+setter
       private String stringValue;//getter+setter

   }
   ```
2. Enclose objects in a wrapper class:

   ```
   public class TeacherWrapper {

       private int intValue;//getter+setter
       private String stringValue;//getter+setter
       private Teacher teacher;//getter+setter

   }
   ```

Of course, you could as well store these two value pairs in two separate lists in your bean, just next to list of `Teacher`, and use EL method call with parameters, if you are on Servlet 3.0 and have EL 2.2.

This way, your command button will do what you desire, if you add the necessary bindings to your input components.

As a side note, be sure to check the reasons behind using session scope for data that most probably belong to view/request scope. Also, you might want to persist a per-row data (like a single `Teacher` object), for which you could add a command button in every datatable row to handle the job, but that's a different question.